# My website isn't responding to a mobile media query on my host service

Tags: html, css, media-queries, cpanel, web-hosting

I hosted a website (ninacressoni.com) and on my brackets, where I edit my website, is fully responsive. But while online, the responsiveness of the mobile disappears.

See, when I just minimize the screen on pc (brackets or website), it responds the way I want. But when I go on inspect ON the website, the mobile screen view is gone. And that is how it looks when I enter my site on a cellphone.

On brackets, even if I open inspect, this responsiveness continues. But on the site itself, it doesn't.

Can someone inspect my code and help me with this situation??? This has been very frustrating since I can't seem to find an answer.

I use Hostgator and they use Cpanel. 
Could this be an error at their host services or could it be programming related?

Ps: Already talked to them and their primary guess is that is a problem with the programming (It seems it isn't because on my brackets the website works and online it works only if you just screen size it without inspect, with inspect nothing happens the way it should on mobile screen and that's how my website appears on a mobile) and in order to get a more advanced help I would need to pay extra.

(Tried explaining with details)

Can someone help this girl out? DESPERATE!!!

Comment: You probably didn't update the files

Answer (score 2):

Your site is missing an important meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

More on responsive meta tag here - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Once this is added, this is what I see on my browser with Inspect Element active

[image]

Since your question lacked any sort of explanation on how the site should look on mobile device, I assume this is what you want the site to look after all.

Comment: Yes, lacked that explaination on how should look but I gave the website where you could see, right?

Comment: He is saying you need to add the meta viewport tag to your site's `<head>`. Without it the site tries to render at the same width regardless of screen size. You also have a lot of assets not loading, check the console.